# Execute on all players within stored distance

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to execute a command on all players withhin a distance from an armorstand (Let's call him "A"). The distance is stored in the scoreboard "Distance" for that armorstand ("Distance" of A is e.g. 13). This means that `execute as @e[name=A] at @s as @a[distance=..13] ...` doesn't do the trick, because the 13 is a constant here and I don't really want a command for every possible distance from 1 to 100.

I had the idea to store the distance of all players to that armorstand in their "Distance"-score and then compare the 2 scores for every player. But I don't know a way to store the distance in an scoreboard or to get it with a command.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't do the trick....from 1 to 100"? Also, by "comparing distance, do you want to find the nearest player?

Comment: @fasterthanlight I would need one command for every possible distance, which I don't want if avoidable. But I also want to be able to change the distance for the armorstand without changing the code.

Comment: Have you tried taking a scoreboard variable and tweaking it with seperate commands, and taking that value as the max distance?

Comment: @fasterthanlight This pretty much exactly the question. How do I take that value as the max distance?

Comment: Ok, so you want nothing else but that, right?

Comment: Related: [How to use a dummy's scoreboard value inside a command](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/375457/258250)

Comment: @fasterthanlight Yes. I want one command that works no matter what value is inside of the Distance variable of A. (Ignoring negative values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution on YouTube:

.

Here is essentially what he is doing:

- Take first entity with as `@e[tag=a]`, Take the second entity with `at @e[sort=nearest,limit=1]`
- Read and store the Position of both entities with

```
execute store result score @s math_in run data get entity @s Pos[0] 100
```

- Compute the lengths x2-x1, y2-y1, z2-z1, square and add them
- To compute the square root, he states to use the `Newton-Raphson, 4 iterations approach`. I don't have the math skills to quickly understand that method, but the results the datapack give are correct. To get the full list of commands, download his datapack.